# counting the element of two arrays that are factors of an number

Tags: java

why my code doesnt work I want to count the number of integers that satisfy the 2 condition:

1-The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being considered

2-The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array

```
public class Betweentest {

   public static int getTotalX(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {

     Boolean test = true;
     int n=0;

     for(int j=2; j<=b.get(b.size()-1); j++){
        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
            if(j%a.get(i) != 0){
             test = false;

            }

         }
        if(test == true){
            for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++){
                if(b.get(i)%j != 0){
                 test = false;

                }
            }
       if(test == true){
         n++;
       }
     }
     return n;
     }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a=Arrays.asList( 2, 4);
       List<Integer> b=Arrays.asList( 16, 32, 64);
         System.out.print(getTotalX( a,  b));
      }

 }
```

Comment: *why my code doesn't work* is not a problem description, please explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: "does not work": please be a bit more specific. What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: i want to count all integers that satisfy the 2 condition above

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you set your indicator variable `test` to `true` only once, before the outer loop begins, so once it changes to `false` (which happens for the first value of `j`), it remains `false` for all the following values of `j`.

It should be reset inside the loop:

```
for (int j=2; j<=b.get(b.size()-1); j++) {
    test = true;
    ...
}
```

Or even better - just declare it inside the loop, since it is not required outside the loop:

```
for (int j=2; j<=b.get(b.size()-1); j++) {
    boolean test = true;
    ...
}
```

After making this change, your code produces the expected result `3` for the given input `List`s.

Answer (score 0):

That's solution maybe can help you

```
boolean result =list1.stream().allMatch(n -> n % divisor ==0);
if(result)
    result =list2.stream().allMatch( n-> n % divisor == 0);

System.out.println("result -->" + result);
```